# Using Sphinx to Index MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I've tried googling this but I'm not sure if my terminology is wrong or I have the wrong idea on how to use Sphinx.

I need some help with creating and searching a index of a table from a database using something like sphinx. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

My sphinx configuration file looks like this:

```
source db1
{
        sql_host                = localhost
        sql_user                = user1
        sql_pass                = pswd123
        sql_db                  = db1
        sql_port                = 3306

        type      = mysql
        sql_query = SELECT * FROM MetaData;
}

index myidx
{
    source            = mureinome
    path              = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/myidx
    docinfo           = extern

    # Added after suggestion from Mihai
    min_stemming_len  = 1
    min_word_len      = 1
    dict              = keywords
}
indexer
{
        mem_limit    = 1000M
        write_buffer = 50M
}
searchd
{
        listen                  = 9312
        listen                  = 9306:mysql41
        pid_file                = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
        binlog_path             = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data
}
```

To index the table I run:

```
root@M4:/var/lib/sphinxsearch# indexer myidx --rotate
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'myidx'...
WARNING: Attribute count is 0: switching to none docinfo
collected 1 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 1 docs, 459 bytes
total 0.005 sec, 80286 bytes/sec, 174.91 docs/sec
total 3 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.6 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 9 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.6 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=2444).
```

But when I try to search the index I get an empty result:

```
SELECT * FROM myidx WHERE MATCH('FC') LIMIT 0,5;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

In MySQL One of the columns in the table looks like this:

```
mysql> select SampleName from MetaData;
+-----------------+
| SampleName      |
+-----------------+
| FCPG1048_S1S2S3 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Am I indexing the table wrong or am I searching the index wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dont know much about Sphinx but in Mysql when doing FULLTEXT search there is a minimum word length,see here in the `Configuring Minimum and Maximum Word Length` section http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html I dont know how this translates to Sphinx. Just use a longer word to search to test it

Comment: Off-course seems so obvious now that you say it! Searching for the whole string works.

Comment: Also watch out for stop words list ,word that are so common that are ignored https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Comment: Okay, thank you, I didn't realize this was a thing it's good to.

Comment: I've tried setting stemming length and word length as per your suggestions I've also swithced to use keywords and it seems like the default options for stopwords is NULL.

Comment: I see where my error is now, I think MATCH matches to words separated by spaces since this configuration seems to work when searching for words present in other fields. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable part word matching need to use `min_prefix_len` or `min_infix_len`

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-prefix-len

Once done that can use a * in the query. Or use `expand_keywords` to effectivly do it automatically.